# errors of findcontours of cv2

Tags: python, opencv

executing following code for removing finger parts of images

```
def remove_fingers(image_bf, mask_color):
    image_array = np.array(image_bf, dtype=np.uint8)
    height, width, _ = image_array.shape

    # RGB to hsv
    hsv_array = np.array([[rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b) for (r, g, b) in row] for row in image_array])

    # decide masking color
    lower_skin = (0, 15, 20)
    upper_skin = (35, 100, 100)
    lower_skin_2 = (320, 15, 20)
    upper_skin_2 = (360, 100, 100)

    # making mask
    mask = hsv_filter(hsv_array, lower_skin, upper_skin) | hsv_filter(hsv_array, lower_skin_2, upper_skin_2)
    print(mask.dtype)  # Output: bool
    print(mask.shape)  # Output: (height, width)

    mask = (mask.astype(np.uint8)) * 255

    print(mask.dtype)  # Output: uint8
    print(mask.shape)  # Output: (height, width)
    print(np.unique(mask))  # Output: array([0, 255], dtype=uint8)  
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I confirmed "mask" has [0 255], so there seems not to be problems in passing arguments in findCoutour. A few month ago, which was before changing some envs, this code had no problems.

I have errors as follows.

> contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'findContours'
> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'image'

before this time, this program had done well. maybe due to change of environment like cv2? matplotlib?, this code does not work well. input data must be OK with my confirmation.

Comment: [mre] required. your claims about the dtype and shape of `mask` don't align with the error message.

Comment: What is ur OpenCV version?

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)